# socket.io The connection to ws:// was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: socket.io

I don't know why but I am still getting this error on my website (hosted on nodejitsu.com).
If am I testing project on localhost everything goes well, but if I open it in browser this error is showing..

I was searching for this issue, but I didn't find anything usefull..

Comment: answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140414/websocket-interrupted-while-page-is-loading-on-firefox-for-socket-io

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    socket.close();
});
```