# Websocket fails in Firefox

Tags: objective-c, google-chrome, firefox, websocket

I am using [PocketSocket](https://github.com/zwopple/PocketSocket) as a LAN WebSocket server (on port 8080) on iOS and I connect to it using javascript.

Here is the javascript code:

```
var address = 'ws://' + window.location.host + ':8080/ws';
client = new WebSocket( address );
```

I have tested the connection using the fallowing browsers:
Chrome (Windows and OS X), Safari (OS X and iPhone), Opera (Windows), Android Browser, the browser on Panasonic TV.

The only browser that it failed was Firefox (Windows and OS X). I have tried multiple versions of Firefox from version 5 to 40. I have also tried using MozWebSocket, but at no avail.

The error that I get is:

```
    Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://192.168.0.100:8080/ws.

    The connection to ws://192.168.0.100:8080/ws was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

What is different in Firefox from the other browsers?
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: ..and it's not the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140414/websocket-interrupted-while-page-is-loading-on-firefox-for-socket-io ?

Comment: In that case the Websocket is interrupted when the page is refreshed on firefox, in my case the websocket doesn't connect at all. In my case i am pretty sure that the problem lies with the Websocket server implementation in objective c.

Comment: In that case the problem does not appear to be browser related. In my case the websocket fails only firefox, I could not find any other browser in which it fails

Comment: I'm running into this too. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had to do with "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate". Setting network.websocket.extensions.permessage-deflate to false in about:config inside Firefox solved the problem.

Also disabling permessage-deflate from the websocket server would fix the problem.