# Websocket connection is closed immediately with Firefox latest version

Tags: firefox, websocket

I tried to test "http://www.websocket.org/echo.html" with http connection in FireFox latest version(Windows7). The connection is immediately disconnected.

The request header:

```
GET /?encoding=text HTTP/1.1

Host: echo.websocket.org

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

Origin: http://www.websocket.org

Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate

Sec-WebSocket-Key: iQ7GU12G5o0sFU84//okZA==

Cookie: __utma=9925811.597070873.1442820609.1442825475.1442833382.3; __utmz=9925811.1442825475.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utmb=9925811.15.10.1442833382; __utmc=9925811

Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade

Pragma: no-cache

Cache-Control: no-cache

Upgrade: websocket
```

And Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, authorization, x-websocket-extensions, x-websocket-version, x-websocket-protocol

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.websocket.org

Connection: Upgrade

Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2015 12:32:27 GMT

Sec-WebSocket-Accept: fwI7KlWcFntRx/98c6OQFUAXH8c=

Server: Kaazing Gateway

Upgrade: websocket
```

I dont understand why? Actually our internal application is implemented with websockets. It is working fine with IE and Chrome. So I tried whether this demo works with FireFox. It is surprise to me to see the result.

Comment: have you tried to enable `Use secure WebSocket (TLS)` ?

Comment: With TLS it works fine. However it should also work with without TLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works with TLS, but not without, it means there is a proxy in the middle of the way messing with your connections. Probably something your ISP has. Some proxies do not play along very well with WebSokets, and that is why WSS:// is recomended most of the time.

[How HTML5 Web Sockets Interact With Proxy Servers](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers)

Comment: Yes, it could be. But why only with FireFox? With IE -11 and Chrome (latest), it is working fine

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627450/websocket-fails-in-firefox ? It may be also a problem with a plug-in you have installed.

Comment: I do not have any plugins. I believe problem most likely with proxy server settings