# WDS disconnected! constantly appear

Tags: firefox, websocket, webpack, webpack-dev-server, sockjs

Running webpack-dev-server is fine. First page load is ok. But when I refresh the browser, every 2 seconds 'WDS disconnected' appears in console and browser reload infinitely. This problem only appear in **Firefox/Firefox Developer Edition browser**. There is no problems in browsers Chrome, Edge, IE11 .
[image: Console. Error trace]

```
package.json:
....
"webpack": "^1.13.3",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"

webpack.config.js:
....
entry: [
    //'app': './app/app.ts'
 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/', './app/app.ts'

],
output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: 'app/app.bundle.js'
},
....
```

Firefox Developer Edition 51.0a2

Comment: This bug may occur after fixing this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140414/websocket-interrupted-while-page-is-loading-on-firefox-for-socket-io

Comment: This looks like the same thing happening in [issue #544](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/544) over in the webpack-dev-server repo. I've created a minimal test case to reproduce. Waiting for someone else to verify.