# node.js - get disconnect event with socket.io with xhr-polling

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, dom-events

Can someone tell me how to get disconnect event with `socket.io` with `xhr-polling` in `node.js` please?

This example not working with `xhr-polling` but works with `websockets`..

```
/* Basics */

var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(1337, null);

io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile("index.html");
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});

var online_clients = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("SOMEONE LEFT");
    });
});
```

So how to get disconnect event with `xhr-pooling`?

Answer (score 1):

The xhr-polling implementation in socket.io does not emit disconnect event when the connection is closed, see [github issue #431](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/431).

You can ask socket.io's client to notify the server about disconnect by turning on the `sync disconnect on unload` flag:

```
// the browser (HTML) side
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost', {
  'sync disconnect on unload': true
});
```

Warning: this option can worsen the user experience when the network and/or your server are slow, see this [pull request](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/pull/469) for more information.

Related questions:

- [socket.io force a disconnect over XHR-polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043893/socket-io-force-a-disconnect-over-xhr-polling)
- [socket.io - disconnect event doesn't fire in xhr-polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954395/socket-io-disconnect-event-doesnt-fire-in-xhr-polling)