# node.js - how to get disconnect event with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, dom-events

Can someone tell me how to get disconnect event with `socket.io` with `xhr-polling` in `node.js` please?

This example not working with `xhr-polling` but works with `websockets`..

```
/* Basics */

var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(1337, null);

io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']); // If I change it to websockets it works!

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile("index.html");
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});

var online_clients = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("SOMEONE LEFT");
    });
});
```

So how to get disconnect event with `xhr-pooling`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043893/socket-io-force-a-disconnect-over-xhr-polling