# socket.io xhr-polling disconnect event

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket.io node script with:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {    
  console.log('disconnect!');
});
```

When I connect with Chrome / Safari and close the page, I see 'disconnect!' in my server console.

However, when I connect with my iPhone and close the page, I don't see this message.  I see `debug - xhr-polling closed due to exceeded duration`

How do I receive the disconnect event with iOS?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone to test with, but if I were you, I'd run a packet capture program like Wireshark on the server side, and see exactly what the packets look like in the "good" and "bad" cases.  There will probably be a clue there in terms of how the iPhone is managing its session.

Comment: Does your iPhone Safari supports websockets fully. See http://caniuse.com/websockets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket.io switches to the xhr-polling transport when you are viewing the page in your iPhone. This might be caused by the configuration of socket.io or because the browser in your iPhone does not (fully) support websockets.

The xhr-polling implementation in socket.io does not emit disconnect event when the connection is closed, see [github issue #431](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/431). You can reproduce this issue in your Chrome browser by forcing the socket.io server to use the xhr-polling transport only:

```
// the server side
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
```

Good news: you can ask socket.io's client to notify the server about disconnect by turning on the `sync disconnect on unload` flag:

```
// the browser (HTML) side
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost', {
  'sync disconnect on unload': true
});
```

Warning: this option can worsen the user experience when the network and/or your server are slow, see this [pull request](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/pull/469) for more information.

**UPDATE**

According to [socket.io force a disconnect over XHR-polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043893/socket-io-force-a-disconnect-over-xhr-polling), setting `sync disconnect on unload` might not be enough to fix the problem on iPhone/iPad.

As you can see in socket.io-client [source code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/0.9/lib/socket.js#L55), `sync disconnect on unload` sets up a listener for `beforeunload` event, which is not supported by iOS Safari according.

The solution is probably to fix socket.io-client to listen for both `unload` and `pagehide` events, because 
*the unload event may not work as expected for back and forward optimization. Use the pageshow and pagehide events instead.* [[Apple Web Content Guide]](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I had found the 'sync disconnect on unload' option, but, it did not solve the problem.  Tricky.  Ideally I'd like to handle this from the server-end.