# Socket.IO not getting disconnect event on polling

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My browser is defaulting to "polling" method, causing me not to get the disconnect event on the server side.

I've tried the solution covered in [socket.io force a disconnect over XHR-polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043893/socket-io-force-a-disconnect-over-xhr-polling) but this didn't do the trick for me:

```
Server.socket = io.connect("https://somedomain:8443", {"sync disconnect on unload":true, secure:true});
```

How can I track users leaving my server with polling?

Comment: Why are you allowing polling in the first place?

Comment: as a fallback to websocket which is not supported in all mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, apparently for some reason the heartbeat timeout was too long for me to think the disconnect mechanism was working.

I changed the timings:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {'pingInterval': 4000, 'pingTimeout': 8000});
```

In the server, and after 8 seconds, sure thing, I get the disconnect event.
The low numbers are because I'm creating a multiplayer game...

Comment: You can accept your own answer here to indicate to the community that this question is now answered.