# jetty 9, websockets and closing websocket connection on server side

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an application that uses a websocket server based on jetty 8. Everything is working great, and when the user refreshes the page, closes the page or move to another page the connection is closed and, on the server side the onClose event is triggered.

I just moved to jetty 9 and in firefox everything works the same ( on refresh the connection is closed) but not on chrome or opera. I even close the browsers and the onClose event didn't triggered.

I know jetty 9 only supports the latest websockets protocol version, and I wanna know if the browser is sending some message to the server when the user refreshed the page for example, and how to handle this on jetty or do I have to handle this in javascript like in this example : [Closing WebSocket correctly (HTML5, Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812686/closing-websocket-correctly-html5-javascript) using `window.onbeforeunload` ?

I would preffer if I can handle all the work on the server side.  Thanks

**UPDATE**
**If I close the connection from the client using ws.close() everything works great.**

Comment: interesting. do you receive "error" events on server?

Comment: There is a bug filed for this in the past 24 hours.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/406449

Comment: @zhong.j.yu no.  no errors are triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few close and disconnect detection bugs in Jetty 9.0.0

- [406449](https://bugs.eclipse.org/406449) - Session's disconnect not detected
- [404991](https://bugs.eclipse.org/404911) - WebSocketCloseTest fails spuriously

Both of those were recently fixed and delivered in [Jetty 9.0.3.v20130506](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00049.html) please give that version a try.